# Extract lines from a file only once using shell/python/perl

Tags: python, perl, bash, shell

I have a big file with numbers, for example:

```
cat $file
3120987654
3106982658
3420787642
3210957659
3320987654
3520987654
    .
    .
    .
```

Daily I extract some numbers of the big file and save this date numbers in second file. Each day new numbers are added to the source data in my big file. I need to make a filter for the extracting job that ensures I do not extract numbers I have already extracted. How might I do this as `bash`  or  `python` script?

Note: I can not remove the numbers of from the source data "big file" I need it to remain intact, because when I finish extracting numbers from the file, I need the original + updated data for the next day's job. If I create a copy of the file and I remove the numbers of the copy, the new numbers that are added are not taken into consideration.

Comment: Are they always appended to the end of the file?

Comment: You don't say how you are currently extracting these records. Is it with `$SHELL` commands, `python`, or in some other manner? How is the file updated?  Do you need locking during extraction?

Comment: @Alexander  I tried to clarify and remove some of the repetitive parts of your post  (the changes may take a while to appear) - especially the last paragraph - by editing the phrasing a bit. Since I am not certain what you meant to say, can you affirm that this adequately captures the sense of your original question?

Comment: Do you just want to use `$SHELL` tools like `comm` and `uniq` here or is the problem more complex?  Are there duplicate lines in the data source "Big File"?  `sort source.txt | uniq -u` will give you the unique lines from your "big file". But I'm not sure what you mean by "lines not repeated". Do you mean the extracted lines should be excluded in the next selection (i.e. selection "without replacement")?

Answer (score 2):

Read in *all* numbers from the big file into a set, then test new numbers against that:

```
with open('bigfile.txt') as bigfile:
    existing_numbers = {n.strip() for n in bigfile}

with open('newfile.txt') as newfile, open('bigfile.txt', 'w') as bigfile:
    for number in newfile:
        number = number.strip()
        if number not in existing_numbers:
            bigfile.write(number + '\n')
```

This adds numbers not already in `bigfile` to the end, in as efficient a way as possible.

If `bigfile` becomes too big for the above to run efficiently, you may need to use a database instead.

Comment: Small typo in first line `bigbile` instead of `bigfile`.  Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can save a sorted version of your source files and extracted data to temporary files and you could use a standard POSIX tool like `comm` to show the common lines/records.  Those lines record would be the basis of the "filter" you'd use in your subsequent extract jobs. If you are extracting records from the `source.txt` file with `$SHELL` commands then something like `grep -v [list of common lines]` would be part of your script -a long with whatever other criteria you are using for extracting the records. For best results the `source.txt` and `extracted.txt` files should be sorted.

Here's a quick cut and paste of typical `comm` output.  The sequence shows the "Big File", the extracted data, and then the final `comm` command which shows lines unique to the `source.txt` file (see `man comm(1)` for how `comm` works).  Following that is an example of searching using an arbitrary pattern with `grep` and as a "filter" excluding the common files.

```
% cat source.txt                           
3120987654
3106982658
3420787642
3210957659
3320987654
3520987654
3520987754
3520987954
3520988654
3520987444

% cat extracted.txt 
3120987654
3106982658
3420787642
3210957659
3320987654

% comm -2 -3 source.txt extracted.txt  # show lines only in source.txt
3520987754
3520987954
3520988654
3520987444
```

`comm` selects or rejects lines common to two files. The utility conforms to IEEE Std 1003.2-1992 (“POSIX.2”). We can save its output for use with `grep`:

```
% comm -1 -2 source.txt extracted.txt | sort > common.txt
% grep -v -f common.txt source.txt | grep -E ".*444$"
```

This would `grep` the `source.txt` files and exclude lines common to `source.txt` and `extracted.txt`; then pipe (`|`) and `grep` these "filtered" results for a new record to extract (in this case a line or lines ending in "444"). If the files are very large or if you want to preserve the order of the numbers in original file and the extracted data, then the question is more complex and the response will need to be more elaborate.

See my other response or the start of a simplistic alternative approach that uses `perl`.

Comment: oops that was supposed to be a comment / question

Comment: @Martijn - yes it was but now that I've answered I can't erase what I've said :-)  ... I will try to make a more useful answer out of it somehow ...

Comment: @MartijnPieters you have so much reputation you forget what it's like ;-)  The posts hang around waiting to be "undeleted" so it's irritating.  I edited my post to hopefully make it a bit more useful. Sorry about the noise.  I think the OP needs a bit of editing as well for clarity and grammar. Will try to get to it later.

Comment: Fair enough; you could just have posted a *new* answer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're not asking for unique values, but you want all the new values added since the last time you looked at the file?

Assume the BigFile gets new data all the time.

We want DailyFilemm_dd_yy to contain the new numbers received during the previous 24 hours.

This script will do what you want. Run it each day.

```
BigFile=bigfile
DailyFile=dailyfile
today=$(date +"%m_%d_%Y")
# Get the month, day, year for yesterday.
yesterday=$(date -jf "%s" $(($(date +"%s") - 86400)) +"%m_%d_%Y")

cp $BigFile $BigFile$today
comm -23 $BigFile $BigFile$yesterday > $DailyFile$today
rm $BigFile$yesterday
```

`comm` shows the lines not in both files.

Example of comm:

```
#values added to big file
echo '111
222
333' > big

cp big yesterday

# New values added to big file over the day
echo '444
555' >> big

# Find out what values were added.
comm -23 big yesterday > today
cat today
```

### output

```
444
555
```

Answer (score 0):

Lazyish `perl` approach.

Just write your own `selection()` subroutine to replace `grep {/.*444$/}` ;-)

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl  
use strict; use warnings; use autodie;                      
use 5.16.0 ; 

use Tie::File;        
use Array::Utils qw(:all); 

tie my @source, 'Tie::File', 'source.txt' ;               
tie my @extracted, 'Tie::File', 'extracted.txt' ;

# Find the intersection                                                   
my @common = intersect(@source, @extracted);                      

say "Numbers already extracted"; 
say for @common       

untie @@source;
untie @extracted;
```

Once the `source.txt` file has been updated you could select from it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl  
use strict; use warnings; use autodie;              
use 5.16.0 ; 

use Tie::File;        
use Array::Utils qw(:all); 

tie my @source, 'Tie::File', 'source.txt' ;               
tie my @extracted, 'Tie::File', 'extracted.txt' ;

# Find the intersection                                                   
my @common = intersect(@source, @extracted);                      

# Select from source.txt excluding numbers already selected:
my @newselect = array_minus(@source, @common);
say "new selection:";
# grep returns list $selection needs "()" for list context.
my ($selection) = grep {/.*444$/} @newselect; 
push @extracted, $selection ;
say "updated extracted.txt" ; 

untie @@source;
untie @extracted;
```

This uses two modules ... succinct and idiomatic versions welcome!